# Admob sending adult content, how to disable this?

Tags: android, admob, google-play

I have just completed my first App and I am using Admob to publish adverts. But before I upload to the google play store I have been testing on my device. Everything was going ok until later this evening, when Admob starting advertising adult content.

There any way to disable this, I don't want to get my account disabled if someone downloads my Apps and takes offence at my App. And for some reason it also seems to display the same adult content.

Under App Settings I have these enabled:

- "Use keyword-targeted ads and Google certified ad networks (GCANs) to improve fill rate"
- "Allow the use of +1 related features and social annotations in ads"

Under Ad filter I have this setting:

- "Age Appropriate Ads" which is turned off

I'm using Android Studio 0.4.6.

Comment: Did you mean Admob? Is that a typo?

Comment: Do you mean AdMob? If so, AdMob says this: " Examples of age appropriate advertising are gambling and personals ads. AdMob does not accept ads that promote adult products or services." So it is surprising that you are seeing Adult content

Comment: I would say its on the border line of adult content. There is a picture of a sexy asian women.

Comment: @donfuxx, Yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can goto <strike>https://apps.admob.com</strike> to change the settings of the type of ads which will be displayed on your app

**Updated:**

https://apps.admob.com/#monetize/pubcontrols:urls

Comment: Age Appropriate Ads - has been turned off. So I don't think I should be getting this adult ad. Always the same one. I haven't publish in the google store yet. As I want to be certain I don't break any rules.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question already that the ad settings have been configured.

Answer (score 1):

You need turn off ads from sensitive categories:
https://apps.admob.com/v2/pubcontrols/sensitive-categories