# Can I prevent ads not appropriate for children in AdMob?

Tags: admob

I have created an educational app. I have integrated ads in it but I want to prevent adult ads. Can I prevent ads not appropriate for children in AdMob so that children can have nice experience while learning something?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955700/admob-sending-adult-content-how-to-disable-this

Comment: @Blisskarthik I don't see any option mentioned in that link answer in the new version of admob.tht answer is true for legacy admob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to manage what kind of ads you want to display in your application.

You can find the option in settings of Ads.

As Legacy AdMob will be deprecated. So you can upgrade to the new AdMob.

[Check Out](https://apps.admob.com)

Comment: I don't see any option like this in Account Settings where i can enable age appropriate ads

Comment: @user3684678 I'm in office right now. Will be able to give exact link once I go home.

Comment: @user3684678 Good ! I'm Happy ! N Sorry I could not give you proper link as I cannot access AdMob in office.